# Does $\mathbb{E}[f_i(X) \mid g_i(X)] = 0, \forall i \in [n]$ imply $\mathbb{E}[f_{j(X)}(X) \mid g_{j(X)}(X)] = 0$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I am trying to prove/disprove that if $\mathbb{E}[f_i(X) \mid g_i(X)] = 0$ for all $i \in [n]$, then $\mathbb{E}[f_{j(X)}(X) \mid g_{j(X)}(X)] = 0$ for any function $j : \mathbb{R} \to [n]$, where $X$ is a real-valued random variable.

I have tried expanding out the definition of conditional expectation, but I am not able to make any progress. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$, $g_i(x)=0$, $f_i(x)=2\mathbb{1}(x=i)-1$, $j(x)=x$?

Comment: Thanks @user51547 for the great counterexample. It is super helpful!